# Shortcut for does not exist

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, do

I am currently programming an application, and as it turns out the term "Does not exist" is commonly shortened to "Not exists". I was curious which would be the more proper term because to me "Not exist" seems more fitting since the missing "s" is added to the "do" rather than "exist".

Comment: Computer terms are generally quite terse, and do not follow the rules of general usage.

Comment: We have no idea of the context of your app which as already stated exists in a different language sphere from this site. However two words seems to me one too many. I would be tempted to venture into the great unknown.

Comment: Computer code can be abrupt with no complaints from developers. If your application faces out to non-technical people, however, wording must be clear. *Not exists* is not clear. *Not exist* is not better. Perhaps *Not found* or *No match*.

Comment: It seems to me that this phrase "Not Exists" is just the pronunciation of a common written shorthand in which negations are reflected by a single symbol in front. For example White might be contrasted with ~White. The pronunciation "Not White." would be intended to preserve the written syntax. If not for that demand, we could say "is not," for example.

Comment: I think the "shortcut" is nonexistent.

Comment: Instead of the expected form (1) “The unicorn does not exist,” your colleagues say (2) “The unicorn not exists." You prefer (3)"The unicorn not exist" as being closer to form (1). Maybe they prefer form (2) as closer to (4) “The unicorn exists,” which they regard as a more appropriate model. This would bear some analogy to mathematics, where we never consider grammatical issues about singular and plural forms in saying that 10 "is" more than 9 or that 8 minus 6 "is" 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorthand phrases are often ungrammatical, and there isn't much point in asking which of two ungrammatical forms is better. (Neither *not exists* nor *not exist* would make much sense to most people.)

The adjectival version of *does not exist* is *is not* ***existing***. But that sounds odd as a statement—and it doesn't shorten the phrase.

However, if you want a single word, you can just use [**nonexistent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonexistent):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : not in actual or present occurrence : not existing